# Como criar uma função em python para conectar o sql server?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, funções

Para resumir o processo de conexão, estou tentando criar uma função para conectar o bando de dados, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a conexão como esperado:

```
def conectar_com_banco(usuario):
    if usuario in 'illuminati':
        username = 'illuminati' 
        password = 'fnord'
    elif usuario in 'fascist_firewall':
        username = 'tor' 
        password = 'onion'
    else:
        print('usuario_nao_encontrado')
    import pyodbc
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER = SQL Server; SERVER = conspiracy; DATABASE = illuminati; UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
    cnxn.cursor()
    return(cursor)
cursor=conectar_com_banco('illu')
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
print(row)
```

Quando rodo esta código, recebo a seguinte resposta:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-d96fceb45081>", line 18, in <module>
cursor=conectar_com_banco('illu')

  File "<ipython-input-4-d96fceb45081>", line 14, in conectar_com_banco
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER = SQL Server; SERVER = conspiracy; DATABASE = illuminati; UID='+username+';PWD='+password)

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Quando a resposta certa seria a versão do meu banco de dados como ocorre na referencia: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017 , que utilizei de exemplo para fazer a conecção simplas.

**Resolução:**

O erro ocorria em:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER = SQL Server; SERVER = conspiracy; DATABASE = illuminati; UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
```

Assim reescrevi da seguinte forma:

```
def conectar_com_banco(usuario):
    if usuario in 'illuminati':
        server = 'conspiracy' 
        database = 'illuminati' 
        username = 'illuminati' 
        password = 'fnord' 
    elif usuario in 'fascist_firewall':
        server = 'conspiracy' 
        database = 'illuminati'
        username = 'tor' 
        password = 'onion' 
    else:
        print('funcao_nao_encontrado')
    import pyodbc
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cur=cnxn.cursor()
    return(cur)
cursor=conectar_com_banco('illu')
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
print(row)
```

E me retornou o esperado:
`('Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) \n\tDec 10 2010 10:38:40 \n\tCopyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation\n\tEnterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)\n', )`

Ainda não descobri o erro de sintaxe que devo ter cometido.

PS.: Tanto {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} quanto {SQL Server} funcionaram.

Comment: Qual foi sua intenção ao fazer `if usuario in 'illuminati'`?

Comment: Poder declarar: ```usuario='illu'``` e ```usuario in 'illuminati'``` e assim ```Out[3]: True```.

Comment: Se entrar no `else`, quais serão os valores de `username` e `password`?

Comment: A função tem vários ```elif``` antes do ```else```, mas retirei para simplifica-la.

Comment: Ok, vamos tentar simplificar. Se entrar no `else` você apenas exibe uma mensagem e continua a execução da função; nesse caso não existirão as variáveis `username` e `password`. Não seria o caso de parar a execução se entrar no `else`? Além disso, o que está acontecendo no seu programa? Dá algum erro? Qual? Ou se gera um comportamento inesperado, qual é e qual seria o esperado? Por favor, responda tudo isso diretamente na pergunta entrando em [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz mais alguns testes e realmente só consegui simular o mesmo erro que você quando instalo o **ODBC Driver for SQL Serve** na versão errada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando instalo o driver na ultima versão (para SQL Server do 2008 ao 2017) o mesmo código funciona normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link para o driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567) que utilizei.

Com relação ao parâmetro `DRIVER` da string de conexão, o **comum** é utilizar `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};`, porque o mesmo cobre várias **versões** do SQL Server:

- {SQL Server} - released with SQL Server 2000
- {SQL Native Client} - released with SQL Server 2005 (also known as version 9.0)
- {SQL Server Native Client 10.0} - released with SQL Server 2008
- {SQL Server Native Client 11.0} - released with SQL Server 2012
- {ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server} - supports SQL Server 2005 through 2014
- {ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} - supports SQL Server 2005 through 2016
- {ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server} - supports SQL Server 2008 through 2016
- {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} - supports SQL Server 2008 through 2017

Contudo a **versão do driver**, bem como o parâmetro `DRIVER` da string de conexão podem variar, e o `SQL Server` que você está utilizando pode ser o correto para a sua infraestrutura.

No Windows Server + SQL Server 2017 utilizei o seguinte código para testes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""""""
# Conector recomendado na documentação oficial.
import pyodbc


def conectar_mssql_docker(usuario, senha):
    con = pyodbc.connect(
        # Driver que será utilizado na conexão
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        # IP ou nome do servidor.
        'SERVER=192.168.100.178\SQLEXPRESS;'
        # Porta
        'PORT=1433;'
        # Banco que será utilizado.
        'DATABASE=PythonMSSQL;'
        # Nome de usuário.
        f'UID={usuario};'
        # Senha.
        f'PWD={senha}')

    # Criando o cursor que irá executar os comandos SQL (instruções DML, DDL, etc).
    cur = con.cursor()
    return cur


if __name__ == "__main__":
    usuario = str(input('Usuario: '))
    print(usuario)
    senha = str(input('Senha: '))
    print(senha)

    cursor = conectar_mssql_docker(usuario=usuario, senha=senha)
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    print(row[0])
```

Já utilizando o SQL Server no Docker utilize o seguinte código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""""""
# Conector recomendado na documentação oficial.
import pyodbc


def conectar_mssql_docker(senha):
    # Conexão Docker imagem Linux.
    con = pyodbc.connect(
        # Driver que será utilizado na conexão
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        # IP ou nome do servidor\
        'SERVER=192.168.100.118;'
        # Porta
        'PORT=1433;'
        # Banco que será utilizado (Criar banco).
        'DATABASE=tempdb;'
        # Nome de usuário (Usuário default da imagem).
        'UID=SA;'
        # Senha.
        f'PWD={senha}')

    # Criando o cursor que irá executar os comandos SQL (instruções DML, DDL, etc).
    cur = con.cursor()
    return cur


if __name__ == "__main__":
    senha = str(input('Senha: '))
    print(senha)

    cursor = conectar_mssql_docker(senha=senha)
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    print(row[0])
```

Para o código acima foi utilizado o `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-CU11
    container_name: SQLServer
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      # - mssql-volume:/var/opt/mssql
      # - ./data/db:/var/opt/mssql
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: 'Python.123456'
      MSSQL_PID: 'Express'
    # devices:
    #   - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

---

### Outra possibilidade

Este erro também pode estar sendo gerado pela diferença de arquiteturas entre o driver instalado e o Python (Python 32 bits com o driver 64 bits ou vice versa), contudo isso é **mais raro**.

**OBS**: Eu executei com Python 32 e 64 bits e não tive o erro por este motivo.

Para verificar você pode acessar `Painel de Controle\Sistema e Segurança\Ferramentas Administrativas`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu caso o `pyodbc` irá localizar o `ODBC` seja o meu interpretador Python 32 ou 64 bits, visto que possuo ele instalado para as 2 arquiteturas (Meu Windows é 64 bits).

você pode clicar sobre `ODBC Data Sources` com o botão direito e clicar em propriedades e tentar alterar o `destino` entre `%windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe` ou `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe`.

Contudo isso é mais raro e lembre-se de guardar o **destino original**.

Estes foram os problemas mais comuns que tive com bases de dados MS SQL Server.

Comment: Não... Estou correto nisso, quando rodei exatamente como no ([Exemplo microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017)) tive que colocar ```DRIVER = SQL Server``` para funcionar.

Comment: Olá @MárcioMocellin eu editei a resposta com mais informações. Caso você tenha mais detalhes sobre o erro estamos no aguardo.